# Unnest from Table in Snowflake

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot, flatten, unnest

I have the following table:

```
PersonID    CW_MilesRun    PW_MilesRun    CM_MilesRun    PM_MilesRun
1           15             25             35             45         
2           10             20             30             40         
3           5              10             15             20         
...
```

I need to split this table into a vertical table with an id for each field (i.e CD_MilesRun =1, CW_MilesRun = 2, etc) So that my table looks similar to this:

```
PersonID    TimeID    Description    C_MilesRun    P_MilesRun
1           1         Week           15            25
1           2         Month          35            45
2           1         Week           10            20
2           2         Month          30            40
3           1         Week           5             10
3           2         Month          15            20
```

In postgres, I would use something similar to:

```
SELECT
    PersonID
  , unnest(array[1,2]) AS TimeID
  , unnest(array['Week','Month']) AS "Description"
  , unnest(array["CW_MilesRun","CM_MilesRun"]) C_MilesRun
  , unnest(array["PW_MilesRun","PM_MilesRun"]) P_MilesRun
FROM myTableHere
;
```

However, I cannot get a similar function in snowflake to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FLATTEN()` with `LATERAL` to get the result you want, although the query is quite different.

```
with tbl as (select $1 PersonID, $2   CW_MilesRun, $3    PW_MilesRun, $4   CM_MilesRun, $5    PM_MilesRun from values (1, 15, 25, 35, 45),(2, 10, 20, 30, 40),(3, 5, 10, 15, 20))

select
    PersonID,
    t.value[0] TimeID,
    t.value[1] Description,
    iff(t.index=0,CW_MilesRun,CM_MilesRun) C_MilesRun,
    iff(t.index=1,PW_MilesRun,PM_MilesRun) P_MilesRun
from tbl, lateral flatten(parse_json('[[1, "Week"],[2, "Month"]]')) t;

PERSONID    TIMEID  DESCRIPTION C_MILESRUN  P_MILESRUN
1   1   "Week"  15  25
1   2   "Month" 35  45
2   1   "Week"  10  20
2   2   "Month" 30  40
3   1   "Week"  5   10
3   2   "Month" 15  20
```

P.S. Use `t.*` to see what's available after flattening (perhaps that is obvious.)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to get me closer to where I need to be. My table actually has more than the four columns. I just used the four here as an example. Is there an option that doesn't require the inline if statement. Or do I have to nest my if statements (there are 24 columns total).

Comment: I can't think of another way.  Maybe someone smarter will come along ;p

Comment: @NatTaylor found another way ... but not sure which is better ... it's just different :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use [UNPIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot.html) and [NATURAL JOIN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join.html).

Above answer is great ... just like thinking about alternative ways of doing things ... you never know when it might suit your needs - plus exposes you to a couple new cool functions.

[image]

```
with cte as (
select
    1 PersonID,
    15 CW_MilesRun,
    25 PW_MilesRun,
    35 CM_MilesRun,
    45 PM_MilesRun
union
select
    2 PersonID,
    10 CW_MilesRun,
    20 PW_MilesRun,
    30 CM_MilesRun,
    40 PM_MilesRun
union
select
    3 PersonID,
    5 CW_MilesRun,
    10 PW_MilesRun,
    15 CM_MilesRun,
    20 PM_MilesRun
)
select * from
(select
   PersonID,
   CW_MilesRun weekly,
   CM_MilesRun monthly
 from
   cte
) unpivot (C_MilesRun for description in (weekly, monthly)) 
natural join 
(select * from
    (select
       PersonID,
       PW_MilesRun weekly,
       PM_MilesRun monthly
     from
       cte
    ) unpivot (P_MilesRun for description in (weekly, monthly))) f
```